# How to use append with getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display results from getJSON function inside

```
<ul>
<li> item 1 link</li>
<li> item 2 link</li>
<li>item 3 link  </li>
... etc.
</ul>
```

What I've tried is:

```
$.getJSON($URL, function(data) {
                var array = $.map(data, function(item) {
                    return {
                        title: item.title,
                        id: item.id
                    };
                });
                for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                    $('#related-sites').append("<li>"+array.title+"</li>");
                }
            });
```

But I've got an error "Undefined" :/ Please help!

Comment: Try debugging, it should be really the first thing to do, it is easily spotable error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see as why do you need that `$.map` also why do you hard-code loop with index with magic values, also you missed index here `array.title`, try this instead:

```
$.getJSON($URL, function(data) {
  var iHtml = '';
  $.each(data, function(i, item) {
    iHtml += '<li>' + (item.title || '') + '</li>';
  });
  $('#related-sites').append(iHtml);
});
```

**Edited:**

> I need to get only the first ten items

```
$.getJSON($URL, function(data) {
  var iHtml = '';
  $.each(data, function(i, item) {
    if(10 <= i) return false;
    iHtml += '<li>' + (item.title || '') + '</li>';
  });
  $('#related-sites').append(iHtml);
});
```

Comment: I need to get only the first ten items that's why i used for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for property `title` of an array...not the specific items within the array

Change

```
$('#related-sites').append("<li>"+array.title+"</li>");
```

To

```
$('#related-sites').append("<li>"+array[i].title+"</li>");
                                    // ^^^
```

Beyond that your map seems redundant and you could just loop over the data itself and get same results